# How to replace multiple patterns with RegExp

Tags: regex, flutter, regexp-replace

I have phone numbers like `+41 000 0000 000` and currently I only can keep `+` sign with my code but I also need to remove spaces from this numbers.

Here is my current function

```
String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
    return phoneStr.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|D'), (Match m) {
      return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : "";
    });
}
```

How can I remove spaces as well as keeping my `+` signs?

Comment: Replace space with `''`? something like `str.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: @Alireza in flutter says `The method 'replace' isn't defined for the type 'String'.` when we do `str.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: You can use `[^\d+]` and replace with an empty string see https://regex101.com/r/5fprzt/1

Comment: Yes, I said something like .., you can search and probably find a method that can replace string for flutter.

Comment: @Alireza but my question was specific detailed and I needed specific answer for it not `something like` :) thanks anyway it's fixed now.

Comment: Do you need any more help here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved**

I've changed my code to following and its working as it supposed to:

```
String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
    return phoneStr.replaceAll(' ', '').replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'^(\+)|D'), (Match m) {
      return m[0] == "+" ? "+" : "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to match `D`? Can you numbers contain the letter `D` in them?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, only space, dash, plus sign and numbers.

Comment: Well, I believe you wanted to use `\D`, any non-digit. You can do it without a callback in the `replaceAllMapped`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233485/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```dart
String flattenPhoneNumber(String phoneStr) {
    return phoneStr.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?!^\+)\D'), '');
}
```

The following

```dart
print(flattenPhoneNumber("+41 000 0000 000"));
```

prints `+410000000000`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QVaSIn/1/). The `(?!^\+)\D` pattern matches any non-digit char (`\D`) that is not equal to `+` at the start of the string.

Comment: So this will keep plus sign (if any) and remove spaces, dashes?

Comment: @mafortis It will keep `+` at the start of the string and remove all other non-digit chars.

Comment: Nice, later I will test this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, you can use [`replaceAll`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method and replace all spaces with '':

```
String phoneStr = "+41 000 0000 000";
phoneStr = phoneStr.replaceAll(' ', '');
print(phoneStr); //+410000000000
```

Comment: Yes I did that already and shared my final code, thank you

Comment: In your final code you used regex but you don't need this.